# PowerShell Jobs, writing to a file

Tags: powershell, jobs

Having some problems getting a Start-Job script block to output to a file. The following three lines of code work without any problem:

```
$about_name = "C:\0\ps_about_name.txt"
$about = get-help about_* | select Name,Synopsis
if (-not (Test-
Path $about_name)) { ($about | select Name | sort Name | Out-String).replace("[Aa]bout_", "") > $about_name }
```

The file is created in C:\0\

But I need to do a lot of collections like this, so I naturally looked at stacking them in parallel as separate jobs. I followed online examples and so put the last line in the above as a script block invoked by Start-Job:

`Start-Job { if (-not (Test-Path $about_name)) { { ($about | select Name | sort Name | Out-String).replace("[Aa]bout_", "") > $about_name } }`

The Job is created, goes to status Running, and then to status Completed, but *no file is created*. Without Start-Job, all works, with Start-Job, nothing... I've tried a lot of variations on this but cannot get it to create the file. Can someone advise what I am doing wrong in this please?

Comment: This is a scoping problem where variables you define in your current scope aren't defined in the job's scope. You can simply replace `$about_name` and `$about` in your job script block with `$using:about_name` and `$using:about`.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the syntax in your answer as it means that I don't have to define parameters inside the block (so I will use your way as it is more clear and concise) but hcm's answer is also important for me to understand how to approach these so I'll mark that as the answer just as it was the only one set as an answer.

Comment: I think your string replacement code is not working as intended because `.Replace()` does not understand character sets `[]`. You should switch to `-replace` if you want that feature.

Comment: I should have seen that, of course you are correct! I sometimes get them mixed up and I didn't see it here yet. Thanks, that's saved me some time wasted when I would inevitably have to find that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the simplest way to get around this problem by use of the `$using` scope modifier.

```
$about_name = "C:\0\ps_about_name.txt"
$about = get-help about_* | select Name,Synopsis
$sb = { if (-not (Test-Path $using:about_name)) { 
          $using:about.Name -replace '^about_' | Sort-Object > $using:about_name 
        }
      }
Start-Job -Scriptblock $sb
```

**Explanation:**

`$using` allows you to access local variables in a remote command. This is particularly useful when running `Start-Job` and `Invoke-Command`. The syntax is `$using:localvariable`.

This particular problem is a variable scope issue. [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-6) creates a background job with its own scope. When using `-Scriptblock` parameter, you are working within that scope. It does not know about variables defined in your current scope/session. Therefore, you must use a technique that will define the variable within the scope, pass in the variable's value, or access the local scope from the script block. You can read more about scopes at [About_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6).

As an aside, character sets `[]` are not supported in the .NET `.Replace()` method. You need to switch to `-replace` to utilize those. I updated the code to perform the replace using `-replace` case-insensitively.

---

[HCM's perfectly fine solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59424274/11025476) uses a technique that passes the value into the job's script block. By defining a parameter within the script block, you can pass a value into that parameter by use of `-ArgumentList`.

---

Another option is to just define your variables within the `Start-Job` script block.

```
$sb = { $about_name = "C:\0\ps_about_name.txt"
        $about = get-help about_* | select Name,Synopsis
        if (-not (Test-Path $about_name)) { 
          $about.Name -replace '^about_' | Sort-Object > $about_name 
        }
      }
Start-Job -Scriptblock $sb
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got to send your parameters to your job.
This does not work:

```
$file = "C:\temp\_mytest.txt"
start-job {"_" | out-file $file}
```

While this does:

```
$file = "C:\temp\_mytest.txt"
start-job -ArgumentList $file -scriptblock {
    Param($file)
    "_" | out-file $file
}
```